# How can I align two icons on my webpage next to each other?

Tags: html, css

I want to put two icons (link to app store and android store) on my webpage next to each other. I downloaded the sample code from google webpage and from apple page with suggestions of how to use it, and I put it in the html code:

```
<section class="download" id="download">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 text-center wp4">
                        <h1>Seen Enough?</h1>
                        <a href="#todo">
                          <img alt="Android app on Google Play"
                               src="https://developer.android.com/images/brand/en_app_rgb_wo_45.png" />
                        </a>
                        <a href="#todo" target="itunes_store" style="display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;background:url(img/apple.svg) no-repeat;width:165px;height:40px;@media only screen{background-image:url(img/apple.svg);}"></a>
                        <!--<a href="http://tympanus.net/codrops/?p=22554" class="download-btn">Download! <i class="fa fa-download"></i></a> -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

and there's this part of css code:

```
.download {
    padding: 120px 0;
    background-color: #3f6184;
}
.download h1 {
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

However, after doing that, I have the following result:

[image]

they are not aligned perfectly and as you can see - the apple app store icon works as a hyperlink, but covers more space than its own image. How can I fix that? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `display:inline-block` to both `a` ?

Comment: Set `display:inline-block` to both and `vertical-align: top`

Comment: Did a demo here, looks aligned http://jsfiddle.net/vbqkvhjc/

Comment: We need a demo really but this feels like a `vertical-align` issue for `inline block` items

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just `vertical-align` them to `top`

**For Instance,**

```
element.style {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url(https://developer.android.com/images/brand/en_app_rgb_wo_45.png) no-repeat;
  width: 165px;
  height: 60px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bad396sq/1/)**

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, one last thing - can you tell me why the second div is so big http://jsfiddle.net/bad396sq/3/ in comparison to the first one? How can I reduce the clickable area just to the svg image? Thanks!

Comment: Just edit the width and height to accommodate the actual width and height to get the clickable area within the image boundaries. Link below to explain the same. http://jsfiddle.net/bad396sq/4/ .. Hope this helps. - @randomuser1

Comment: Hey, so I change the android icon in your code to apple.svg and I got this result: http://i.imgur.com/XUR3W8E.png as you can see the android hyperlink is way bigger than its picture itself... Is there a way of making the both icons the same size? The updated fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/bad396sq/5/ <-- ok I attached the apple.svg to this fiddle but can't see it on the screen, sorry for that :(

Comment: @randomuser1 - For that, you need to change both the image heights uniformly to achieve what you are looking for. If both are consistent, it will work. Right now, one icon has a bit larger height than the other.

Comment: but how can I change the svg size in this code? When I increase the width: and height: in CSS the only thing that gets bigger is the clickable area, but the svg image stays the same.. Sorry for bothering you with trivial tasks, I'm just starting learing all of this.. Thanks!

Comment: add a `background-size: 270px;` to this code and it would be increasing uniformly. PS: 270px is a tentative dummy value to explain. You can use it as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

`vertical-align:middle;` also help to align images or elements vertically aligned to each other with `display:inline-block` css.